# My MacBook Pro (2011) is saying there are no software updates, however there should be.

Tags: macbook-pro, xcode

My MacBook Pro (2011) is not up to date, however there are no software updates showing. I know it is not up to date because when I try downloading Xcode it says Xcode can's be installed on Macintosh HD, it needs Mac OS X 10.8.4.What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

For OS updates, the software updater only shows minor releases (so if you are running 10.6, you'll get all the 10.6.x updates etc.). In your case you need to upgrade to a more recent major release (10.8 or 10.9).

I would suggest going into the Mac App Store and examining the new OS X Apple release called Mavericks. It is 10.9 and might have several features of interest to you. Before purchasing and installing it though please backup your computer and files (perhaps via Time Machine).

With 10.9 installed you can run the lastest version of Xcode but be aware, I don't know what other programs you have on your system and it could be that older apps and app versions might not support 10.9 at the moment or without further updating ($$$).

Answer (score 1):

I would grab the [10.8.5 Combo update package](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1676) from Apple's downloads page. You can also download the 10.8.4 version if you for some reason don't want the most updated 10.8 version.

Comment: It won't allow me to download this package because it said that Mac OS X is required. My MacBook Pro should still be capable of software updates even though it was purchased in 2011, right?

Comment: Perhaps I made a wrong assumption. What major version of OS X do you have running? Type `sw_vers` in terminal or check the About window from the Apple menu.

Comment: Very helpful pointer, Thank you.  To find the right version for your particular from/to upgrade, you can search here: https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos.  In my case I am looking to upgrade from Sierra to High Sierra